# How to Debug Classic ASP Using Visual Studio

Tags: asp-classic

There is an excellent article available at the following URL (below), but I cannot figure out where I can download a copy of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.  I've looked all over the Internet, but the download links are either not working (those that are at Microsoft), or they go to very suspicious looking websites.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28792/Debugging-Classic-ASP-VBScript-in-Visual-Studio-20

Of course the other question that can be asked is, can this process be adapted to work on the most recent version (or at least a version that can actually be downloaded)?

Comment: Debugging Classic ASP with Modern Visual Studio https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio

Answer (score 2):

Here's one link for you, straight from the horse's hands.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13276

Comment: Thank  you very taking the time to provide your answer.  However, that's for the Service Pack, which requires that Visual Studio 2008 already be installed.

Comment: You may want to read the pre-req paragraph first. SP1 is a complete install. In fact, if you had Windows Studio 2008, it's better to remove it completely before the installation of SP1 to skip all the upgrading steps fiesta.

Comment: Okay, I will try burning it to a DVD and installing again.  I don't understand why people keep giving me down votes just for asking questions.  This site is horrid in that aspect.

Comment: you haven't been to C/C++ section yet, that's where the real jungle is. For an easy ISO handling, try the WinCDEmu utility, it will simply mount your iso image as an OS drive. Very convenient.

Comment: I finally got Visual Studio 2008 installed and functional on our server.  Will be trying it's debugging features next and will provide a final and definitive answer to this question.  Thank you all VERY MUCH for your kind input.  This site is very difficult to use due to the aforementioned "jungle" of people that go out of their way to discredit and put you down.  Horrid.